# How to properly clean and rewrite an array in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

On click on button i get input value and array.

```
<button onClick={()=>this.props.test(this.props.value,this.props.pokemonList)}>Push</button>
```

In action I map it and equalize value "Types" in array with input value and if they equal then put them in state

```
export function filterByTypes(searchValue,pokList){
    return (dispatch) =>{
        dispatch(getValue(searchValue));
        pokList.map((types)=>
        types.types.map((name)=>{
            if (searchValue == name.type.name){
                dispatch(filteredPokes(types));
            }})
        );
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
   case FILTERED_POKES:
      return{
         ...state, filteredPokes: [...state,action.types]
     }
```

I need that every time on click array filteredPokes cleared and put there new elements.
I tryed do like this ...state, filteredPokes: [action.types], but in that case in array put just one element.
How can I fix it or do right check?
Thank you!

Comment: `Dispatch` whole array of required data at once rather than using `map` and calling dispatch again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducer

```
  case FILTERED_POKES:
    return {
         ...state, 
         filteredPokes: [...state.filretedPokes, ...action.types]
    }
```

In your case you copy all `state` to `filteredPokes`. For clearing `filteredPokes` by click create new action.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to filter the array, and then put the array in state

```
 export function filterByTypes(searchValue,pokList){
        return (dispatch) =>{
            dispatch(getValue(searchValue));
            pokList.forEach((types)=> {
            dispatch(filteredPokes(types.types.filter((name)=> searchValue == name.type.name)));
}
        }
    }
```

Comment: this operation coorect in my code.The problem is than i need clean array after click and put there new value